# Granting application role of "storage blob data contributor" in storage account

Tags: azure, powershell, storage, rbac

My goal is to make app a "blob storage contributor" of storage account​.
To do so I am trying to grant application role, but cannot - when trying i encounter an error.

I am trying to do it with this command:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ApplicationId $appId -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceName $resourceName -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' -RoleDefinitionName 'Storage Blob Data Contributor'
```

I am getting an error:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : The provided information does not map to an AD object id.
```

Does anyone know what might be the issue? I checked all parameters, object id is correct for sure (tried objectId and ApplicationId and still not working)

When i did similar thing to grant group role with below command it was successful.

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $groupObjId -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceName $resourceName -RoleDefinitionName 'Reader' -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ApplicationId is different from ObjectId

Comment: Make sure you use the object id of the *service principal* / Enterprise application / Managed app in local directory. It is very confusing, but the Application object is just the template for the service principal, which is the actual target of any permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the AZ Module but the command should be identical with RM module

```
$contributor = Get-AzRoleDefinition "Contributor"
$contributor
$scope = "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/Demo/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<Storage Account name>"
New-AzRoleAssignment -ApplicationId <appicationID> -RoleDefinitionName $contributor.Name -Scope $scope
```

[image]

PS: you can also get Storage account id for scope by;

```
$stracc = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <resourecegroupname> -Name <Storage Account name>
$stracc.Id
```

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Good answer, one thing, OP wanted different role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" is one of the blob data services role. Gives access to data and no access to Azure resources. But OP should be able just to change the name in your script.

Comment: Yes, you can jus change the name of the role, even use custom role if it has already been defined.

Comment: @Hannel I went through your example and i tried it out - still gives me the same error "New-AzRoleAssignment : The provided information does not map to an AD object id." Maybe this doesn't apply when storage account is azure data lake gen2 ? Can you check this out on your side with this storage account type? On my side it simply doesn't work.

Comment: I guess it was an issue with application, created new and now it is working, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full function. The application I use is ADF. In ADF properties ( portal) you can see "Managed Identity Application ID" this is what we are providing here as app id.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $rgName,
    $storageAccountName,
    $adfName
)

#./adls-SetAccessForAdf.ps1 -rgName "myRG" -storageAccountName "mystorage" -adfName "myADF" 

$contributor = Get-AzRoleDefinition "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
$contributor
$stracc = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $storageAccountName
$scope= $stracc.Id

Write-host "scope = " $scope


$objectId=(Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $adfName).Identity.PrincipalId

$appId = (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $objectId).ApplicationId

Write-host "object ID =" $objectId
Write-host "App ID =" $appId

New-AzRoleAssignment -ApplicationId $appId -RoleDefinitionName $contributor.Name -Scope $scope
```